# Delete sql query is very very slow

Tags: sql, ruby, sql-delete

I've a little problem;
I have 2 tables:
`events` and `multimedia`.
`events` have the

```
id, 
device_id
created_at field
```

the primary key is the id and there's a index formed by `device_id` and `created_at` field.

`multimedia` table have the follower field:

```
id
device_id
created_at
data (this field is a blob field and contains a 20k string)
```

the primary key is id and there's a index formed by `device_id` and `created_by` field.

The problem is when i want to delete the record with `created_at` before a data.

the query:

```
DELETE FROM events WHERE device_id = #{dev[0]} 
AND created_at <= '#{mm_critical_time.to_s}'
```

is ok. In 5 or 6 second `delete` the record.

The query

```
DELETE FROM multimedia WHERE device_id = #{dev[0]} 
AND created_at <= '#{mm_critical_time.to_s}'
```

give me some problem, the execution start and never finish it.

what's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to create an index for the columns you are searching.

```
CREATE INDEX device_created_index
ON multimedia (device_id, created_at);
```

If you want to learn more about optimizing your queries, refer to the answer I gave here about using EXPLAIN SELECT: [is there better way to do these mysql queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180902/is-there-better-way-to-do-these-mysql-queries/8181591#8181591)

Comment: Then I suggest you EXPLAIN your queries as mentioned in the answer I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

the order of the conditions is important, you havent't told us your database server but at least in Oracle it is, so try to reverse them like

```
DELETE FROM multimedia WHERE 
created_at <= '#{mm_critical_time.to_s}' 
AND device_id = #{dev[0]}
```

or us an inner query on the fastest part

```
DELETE FROM multimedia WHERE 
created_at <= '#{mm_critical_time.to_s}' 
AND device_id in (select device_id from multimedia where device_id = #{dev[0]})
```

Also, i always break slow queries up and test the parts on speed so that you know where the bottleneck is.
Some programs show you how long a query took and in Ruby you could use benchmark, you can supplement the delete with a select while testing.

so test:

```
select * FROM multimedia WHERE created_at <= '#{mm_critical_time.to_s}'
```

and

```
select * from multimedia WHERE device_id = #{dev[0]}
```

Success..

Answer (score 0):

It is quite naive to give solutions to performance problems in relational databases without knowing the *whole story*, since there are many variables involved.

For the data you provided though, I would suggest you to drop the primary keys and indexes and run:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX uc ON events (device_id, created_at);
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX uc ON multimedia (device_id, created_at);
```

If you really need to enforce the uniqueness of the `id` field, create one unique nonclustered index for this column on each table (but it will cause the delete command to consume more time):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_id ON events (id);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_id ON multimedia (id);
```