# MySql view is very slow. Why?

Tags: mysql, sql

My normal query:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT vt.id as id,
    vtt.name as n,
    vt.etxid as etx
FROM vt
LEFT JOIN vtt ON
    (vtt.locale = "etx"
    AND vtt.etxid = vt.etxid)
```

Execution time: 5ms

My view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW myview AS
SELECT
    DISTINCT vt.id as id,
    vtt.name as n,
    vt.etxid as etx
FROM vt
LEFT JOIN vtt ON
    (vtt.locale = "etx"
    AND vtt.etxid = vt.etxid)
```

My view query:

```
SELECT * from myview;
```

Execution time: 600ms

Comment: Are you certain this is reproducible?  The execution plans, and therefore running times, should be about the same, assuming the same underlying data.  Has the underlying data changed?

Comment: Just to observe, VIEWs in MySQL serve no useful purpose

Comment: The data have not changed.

Comment: found a far better dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760475/mysql-view-performance

Comment: @Strawberry Views do indeed serve a very useful purpose in MySQL.  If you are using a framework like Django, you can avoid using raw sql queries where they would otherwise be necessary by instead having your model point to a view with a precomposed query instead of a table.  That way, you can keep using the regular queryset ORM and keep Django and sql separate.  It is probably the same for other frameworks as well.

Comment: Views are very useful when writing web applications and are associating some persistent entity to a table/view. Very useful when displaying a UI table with one row per persistent entity.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you mention DISTINCT or aggregation functions in a view MySQL selects TEMPTABLE algorithm for this view, and it means it will create a temporary table for the view and then apply sorting, grouping, and aggregations to it. See more details [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-algorithms.html). Also, there are some [recommendations here concerning view performance](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-table-optimization.html).

Comment: I had marked this as a dupe of another Q or two, but then I realised none of them had as good (i.e. cited, non-speculative) an answer as this, so now I've duped them on this :-)